# Get entire string from window.getSelection()

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using `window.getSelection()` to return the highlighted text from one of the containers on my page. It is returning the correct string, however, I would also like to be delete the highlighted text when the user presses backspace. This wouldn't be a problem, however, in the event of duplicate strings, it is currently not possible to know which case to delete. How can I resolve this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-easley-iyk30

```
import React from "react";

const values = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"];

const handleMouseUp = e => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const highlightedText = selection.toString();
  console.log(highlightedText);
  //how to identify index of text?
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div onMouseUp={e => handleMouseUp(e)}>
      {values.map(val => (
        <var>{val}</var>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For example, if one were to highlight the last `abc` substring, it would simply return `abc`, but I would like it to tell me the index information of this particular substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) returns a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object.

Through `Selection.getRangeAt(0)`, you obtain a [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object that has properties [`startOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/startOffset) and [`endOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/endOffset), which can be used to identify the selected text.

```
var selRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selStart = selRange.startOffset; 
var selEnd = selRange.endOffset;
```

**UPDATE**

- [`Range.startOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/startOffset) returns a number representing where in the
  `Range.startContainer` the `Range` starts.
- [`Range.endOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/endOffset)
  returns a number representing where in the `Range.endContainer` the
  `Range` ends.

Your code produces a series of `var` elements that each contains text of a single character. Therefore, we have to consider `Range.startContainer` and `Range.endContainer`, which makes the solution look slightly more complicated.

Please have a look at the following [**Code Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-greider-9cmll).

Comment: I want to identify the index of the highighted text relative to the entire string. For example, if my string is 'abcabc' and the user highlights the second 'abc' substring, I would like to know what index this substring begins from in the context of the entire string, thus in this case it would be the 4th until the 6th.

Comment: @Perplexityy: `startOffset` corresponds to the index of the first selected character while `endOffset - 1` is the index of the last selected character.

Comment: I am not getting any index information from these values. They are only ever 0 or 1, even if I highlight a long string in my input. Can you give me an example with a sandbox, replicating what I'm trying to do, with your solution?

Comment: @Perplexityy: After I noticed that every character is wrapped in a `var` element, I updated my answer with a corresponding new solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

const values = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"];

const handleMouseUp = e1 => {
  const selection = document.getSelection();

  if (selection.toString() !== "") {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", e2 => {
      console.log(e2.key);
      if (e2.key === "Backspace") {
        selection.deleteFromDocument();
      }
    });
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div onMouseUp={e => handleMouseUp(e)}>
      {values.map(val => (
        <var>{val}</var>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This worked for me, there is a `selection.deleteFromDocument()` function that deletes the currently selected DOM.

Comment: This solution is nice, but doesn't quite suffice for what I need. I am trying to identify the index range of the highlighted substring so I can do other things with it, not simply erase whatever is selected from the document.

Comment: For example, if one were to highlight the last abc substring, it would simply return abc, but I would like it to tell me the index information of this particular substring **so it could be safely deleted.**
---------
I thought that's what you ultimately wanted, but I'll keep looking for a way to get the index of the strings.

Comment: I agree that my post was misleading, deleting the substring is my long term intention, but not what I immediately need to do with it, I have since edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

window.getSelection() return object with the highlited text

```
var selObj  

if(window.getSelection()){
//do something
selObj=window.getSelection()
return selObj
}
if(window.getSelection().empty){
selObj={}
}
```